# Automatically mark slf4j parameterized variables?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I am using slf4j. I have lots of log statements that look like this;

```
LOG.debug("I like {} and {}", new Object[] { "foo", "bar" });
```

When this log statement is executed, I get logs that look like this;

```
I like foo and bar
```

As expected. However, I would like log message parameters to have additional formatting, to make it much easier for log parsers. An desired log message that literally looks like this;

```
I like [foo] and [bar]
```

Obviously I could update the literal log statement to `I like [{}] and [{}]`, but this is a lot of change, makes the log statements look unessessarily messy and isn't very flexible for the future.

Could somebody suggest a quicker solution while still keeping with slf4j? The implementation I am using is logback-classic to do the actual lgoging.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for log values in the method's parameters?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Logback, probably you can construct a custom appender/encoder/layout/converter.  In Logback, Appenders are taking in LoggingEvent, which normally delegates to an encoder for which delegate to a layout to construct the message. Have a look on the source code to see which part is the best place for you to do the custom handling.